# How ASP.NET form authentication works: recognising cookies from request

Tags: asp.net, .net, form-authentication

I am reading on form authentication in ASP.NET and cannot understand some moment:

James enters  a username-password, they are saved in the db. A cookie from username is created, encrypted and attached to a response. As I understand then, when we get a request we need to recognise that cookie received are from James and so we can show his customised page.

What I would like to understand is how system will retrieve username form cookie and then load his info from db?

Comment: Using string parsing and SQL (plus some crypto)

Comment: Hm, I don't see any database mentioned in manuals and Apress ASP.NET book. It all looks like a magic in them. I would be happy to know more about how it works.

Comment: You just said "they are saved in the db".  It typically uses SQL Server or Access; it's configured in Web.config

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Forms Auth is storage agnostic. It doesn't have to use a database, indeed you can use it with usernames and passwords in [web.config](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/72wdk8cc%28v=vs.71%29.aspx).

So what happens is

1. A user logs in.
2. The user is authenticated against the membership provider (which can use SQL, Active DIrectory, web.config, Oracle, MySQL, whatever)
3. A forms authentication token is created for the user, and is placed on the user machine via a cookie.
4. Each subsequent request reads the forms authentication token, and queries the provider to get the user details.
5. The user details are used to populate the user identity in the HttpContext and current thread for the request which is then available to your code to use.

In your code you can check the [User](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.page.user.aspx) property in the Page class (WebForms) or the [User](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.controller.user.aspx)  property in the controller class (MVC).

While you can get at it via the current thread, or the current context it's not advised, especially once you start using background tasks, where the identity may not propagate to the thread, or the context may change.

You'll note that nothing is stored in a database when the user logs in. It's all in the forms authentication token, and the work of retrieving the user from it's store on each request is done for you.

Comment: Thanks, I see we can use membership provider to go to MSSQL or use bare Form Auth and do all the work on our own.

Comment: Well if you wanted to do the work on your own (why?!) then the correct way to go about it would be to create your own membership provider, that way the standard ASP.NET pieces could use your custom code.

Comment: Thanks for mentioning properties to use to retrieve username!

Comment: what are the things stored in auth cookie?

Answer (score 1):

Afaik Forms Authentication does not store or load anything in any database. You can use a database to store the username and password, or you can put them in the web.config. How you store user credentials and validate them is up to you, and can happen separately from Forms Authentication.

Once you have validated a user (against database or some other logical storage), you use FormsAuthentication to write the authentication cookie. You do not need to worry about decrypting the cookie.

You can get the username from System.Threading.Thread.CurrentPrincipal.Identity.Name. To retrieve user's info from the database, you would query the database using the value if the principal identity name.

**Response to comments**

Right, you can use forms authentication with the membership provider, active directory, or your own custom user database. FormsAuth doesn't care about the password at all, unless it is stored in web.config (as noted in blowdart's more complete answer). It just writes the cookie, which is decrypted and used to create the thread identity automatically.

**Additional Info**

Even though this was marked as the answer, [blowdart's response](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8898591/304832) is much more complete. You really should not get the identity from the thread if you need it in an ASPX page or MVC controller, use the properties he referenced.

Comment: Thanks. So as I understand, with Form Authentication we can send encrypted cookie. Then when a request came, system checks its cookie info  it decrypts it back to FormsAuthenticationTicket and sets Identity.Name. Then it's all up to us what to do with it. Right?

Comment: @arctic_dev - correct. For handling the authentication, authorization and storing user related information, you can use the [Membership, Role and Profile](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yh26yfzy.aspx) providers in ASP.NET. Or roll your own of course.

Answer (score 0):

You get the username in your web form by calling User.Identity.Name, e.g. like this:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string userName = User.Identity.Name;
}
```

ASP.NET interprets the cookie for you, you don't have to read it yourself. Or is your question how to store the user and password in the DB?